# Is std::string part of the STL?

Tags: c++, string, stl, history

<sup>(When I say STL, I'm talking about the template library that revolves around containers, iterators, algorithms and functors.)</sup>
This question came to mind after thinking that a `std::string` mostly behaves like a normal container, with `begin` and `end` functions (including iterator), a `size` function and the possibility to use all of those for normal STL algorithms that work on containers / ranges through their iterators (e.g. `transform`, `sort`, `find`, etc.).

At the same time, however, it is not a container itself, as it doesn't fit in picture of containers that store arbitary data. Also, it operates on the contained data mostly through member functions, like `substr`, `find_first_of`, etc., while true container don't do that and let the algorithms handle that.

Additionally, the [cplusplus reference site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) and the C++ standard don't list `std::string` together with the real containers, but in a distinct category.
However, on [SGI's STL site](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/index.html), `basic_string` (and consequently the `string` typedef) are mentioned with the other container and the [`basic_string` reference site](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html) states that it belongs to the "containers" category.

Now my question is, is `string` actually part of the STL or is it a distinct library itself?
And if it belongs to the STL now, did it differ in the original STL developed by Stepanov?

Comment: Who cares about the STL at this point, other than for historical curiousity?

Comment: @ildjarn: Well, I like to accumulate knowledge. :P Also, see that little `history` tag? :) I'm just interested in stuff like this, so I ask for it.

Comment: Ah, fair, I actually didn't see the `history` tag :-]

Comment: What's the STL, if not what is defined at the SGI site?

Comment: Did the STL start using the `std` namespace? Isn't that explicitly prohibited by the C++ language standard?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, not really. And yes, kind of.

[There are varying definitions of "the STL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-this-stl-vs-c-standard-library-fight-all-about), including:

- The actual HP/SGI STL, the original library, parts of which the C++ Standard Library was based on. They included containers, iterators and algorithms. Strings were *not* a part of this.
- The parts of the C++ Standard Library that were based on the SGI STL library: containers, iterators and algorithms. Still no strings.
- All of the C++ Standard Library. This definition has absolutely no grounding in logic or reality though, if followed, `std::string` would be included.

Note that the actual STL has developed since C++ was standardised (some 13 years ago, remember), and they've backwards-adopted some of the stuff that went into the standard, like strings. This does *not* mean that they were originally there in 1998... but they are there now for "compatibility" reasons.

---

**Summary**

The STL was containers, algorithms and iterators.

Strings and streams were adopted for C++98, then *backwards*-adopted for the modern SGI STL.

Whether strings are "part of the STL" or not depends on whether you follow logic and reason, or call the standard library "STL".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just one minor note: at least as it was originally distributed, the HP STL actually *did* include a `bstring` (basic string) class (not to be mistaken for `basic_string`), though as I recall it was really only there so they wouldn't have to deal with C-style strings in trivial demo programs (but they apparently didn't want to deal with every compiler having its own unique string class either).

Answer (score 12):

There is no real answer to this. On one hand, `std::string` was developed entirely independently from the other containers. On the other hand, it's had enough added on to meet all the requirements of a random-access container. Whether you choose to classify that as part of "STL" or not is entirely up to you -- in the end, it just points to the fact that "STL" lacks a single, agreed-upon definition, and the chances of it suddenly gaining a clear meaning is remote (to put it nicely).

IOW, "STL" is a lousy abbreviation to use because people use it to mean at least three different things -- but, unfortunately, there's no better abbreviation around with a better defined meaning either, so STL remains in use and will probably continue to do so (and continue to obstruct communication) indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

It is part of STL indeed. And `std::string` is just `basic_string<char>` typedef. It is container, specialized (not in C++ "specialization" meaning :) ) for data storage with string semantics. No idea about Stepanov though.

Worth mentioning is that STL is "Standard Template Library", not only container subpart. That includes algorithms, streams and some traits.

Comment: @Xeo: Huh? Streams, algorithms and iterators are precisely the only things that were adapted from the STL for the standard.

Comment: @Tomalak: Oh, streams. Now I read that as IOstreams, maybe because you had that wrong in your other answer too at first.. >_>"

Comment: @Xeo: The difference being...?

Comment: @Tomalak: Wait. the IOstream hierarchy is not part of the STL, right? At least not in the sense I made clear at the top of my question, no?

Comment: @Xeo: Oops, sorry, indeed of course streams were _not_ in the STL.